# Reactjs How i can pass props from index.html to App component with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hello i want to pass props from index.html    to App.tsx as you see i'm using typescript. so i want to do it with typescript.

my code

//index.html

```
 <div id="root" name="test"></div>  //props name test
```

//Index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

var container =document.getElementById('root');



    ReactDOM.render(
    
    
    <App name={container.getAttribute('name')} />
    
     ,
     container
    );


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

//i'm sorry i should have provided this my knowledge about typescript is very low

//App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <p>{this.props.name}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: That looks good... What is your issue exactly ?

Comment: Because i'm using typscript in index.tsx it says {Type '{ name: string | null} is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<App> & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.}

Comment: Try casting to `any` : `<App name={container.getAttribute('affiliate') as any} />`. That should do it.

Comment: You can't, It has to be a component to component relationship when passing down props

Comment: You need to indicate the props your component accepts. `App extends React.Component<{}, {name: string | null}>`. Please look at some examples there are a lot out there

Answer (score 0):

You should add props to your App component constructor:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    render(){
```